# Implementing structured grid boundary conditions using NumPy arrays?

Tags: finite-difference, python, boundary-conditions, numpy, advection

I am making a toy code in Python to solve the advection equation $$u_t + cu_x = 0$$
with, for example, periodic boundary conditions.

**Background information**

The numerical grid is specified like this:

```
# problem parameters
lx = 2.0*np.pi    # length of the domain
c = 1.0           # advecton speed

# grid generation
nx = 50            # number of grid points
dx = lx/float(nx)  # grid spacing
x = np.linspace(-dx/2.,lx+dx/2.,nx+2) # vector of grid points
```

where the `-dx/2.` and `lx+dx/2.` points correspond to the ghost points.

I currently implement the periodic boundary conditions like this:

```
def periodic_bc(u):
  u[ 0]=u[-2]
  u[-1]=u[ 1]
  return u
```

and the time integration is written as follows:

```
for n in range(0,nt):
    u[1:nx+1] = u0[1:nx+1] + (c*dt/dx)*(u0[0:nx]-u0[1:nx+1])
    u = periodic_bc(u)
    u0 = u
```

where `u0` and `u` are the old and new data, respectively. All arrays are numpy arrays.

**Question**

Does anyone have suggestions for implementing boundary conditions in a more elegant fashion?

Even when I was programming this extremely simple code, I found myself confused about the bounds of my array slices (e.g., `0:nx`, `1:nx+1`) and the implementation of my periodic boundary conditions function. It's not exactly intuitive that `u[0]=u[-2]`. The corresponding Fortran code would be `u[-1]=u[nx-1]`, where `u[-1]` can be allocated specifically for the ghost points. To me this is much more intuitive and matches the discrete boundary conditions.

Or maybe there is a different way besides ghost points that allows a much more intuitive code. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: I thought there may have been a way to embed boundaries like this in `ndarray`s but now I cannot find it in the docs.  The most likely place I would look though is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Numpy function $roll$ performs periodic shift of an array. Using it, the explicit time step for your PDE in a periodic domain can be simply implemented like this:

```py
u = u - (1/2)*(c*dt/dx)*(np.roll(u,-1) - np.roll(u,1))
```